# Что тормозит генерацию страницы ModX - сниппет или база?

Tags: php, mysql, modx

Сделал сниппет для ModX, чтобы вывести на страницу таблицу из базы данных, в таблице 48000 строк:

```html
$area = 'SELECT * FROM `items`';
$query = $modx->query($area);
if ($query) {
    while ($i= $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<area coords="'.$i['x1'].','.$i['y1'].','.$i['x2'].','.$i['y2'].'" href="http://'.$i['href'].'" title="'.$i['title'].'" shape="rect">';
    }
}
```

Результаты вывожу в шаблоне, формируя в теге map кучу зон area

```html
<map id="Map" name="Map">
 [[!Snippet]]
</map>
<img usemap="#Map" id="target" src="assets/img/main.png">
```

Ставлю LIMIT 1000 элементов - все ок, если поднимаю лимит до 5000 и выше - браузер виснет.
Пробовал запускать и на виртуальном хостинге и на выделенном за 20000р в мес - одно и тоже, нагрузку на базу показывают минимальную.
Render time: 0.3190 s
Страница в итоге выводится, визуально секунд 5-10. На айпаде видна только часть старницы(((

Это ограничение браузера или все=таки сниппет коряво сделан?

Comment: и впредь точно укажи какая у тебя версия modx - revo или evo.

Comment: Версия ModX REVO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

48 000 строк для любого браузера мягко говоря дофига. Если нужно вывести кучу точек нужно пользоваться специально предназначенными для подобных задач инструментами - например `ymaps.Clusterer` в яндекс картах.

Comment: спасибо, почитаю. а еще инструменты есть?

Comment: Наверняка. Гугли конкретно под свою задачу и сравнивай.